# assertEquals - always pass test - Android Studio

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, junit

I'm new on junit test. I do not understand where I'm wrong. here is a simple unit tests (which simplifies my real test):

```
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
public class exampleTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    String ob1, ob2;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        ob1 = "hi";
        ob2 = "bye";
    }

   public void  testEx()throws Exception{
       assertEquals("Error", ob1, ob2);
   }
}
```

When I run exampleTest I get that the test always passes.

Where i'm wrong? can someone explain me?

My build.gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.mobile.app.servizi.activity"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/test/java']
        }

    }


    //instruct the Gradle build system to return default values for method calls
    //in the `android.jar`with the following configuration in your Gradle build file.
    testOptions {
        unitTests{
            returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }


}


dependencies {
    compile project(':androidswitchbackport')
    compile project(':librarySlidingMenu')
    compile project(':libraryViewPagerIndicator')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'

    //dependency for Local test
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

}
```

The gradle file has many dependency because the App in question is complex, long and old, and I have the responsibility to make the tests. I would be grateful if you gave me a hand.

Comment: you have to annotate your test method with @Test to make it work

Comment: Thanks a lot @JuanCruzSoler ! But when i insert '@Test' on test method, and correspondingly it is imported 'import org.junit.Test;'   i have this errorS:     'error: package org.junit does not exist '        AND                       'error: cannot find symbol class Test'                what should i do? (sorry i'm new on tests)

Comment: Also in build.gradle file i added the the following commands:    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'      AND    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

Comment: Clarification: Your suggestion it's ok if I apply it on a test of a sample project (Calculator), but if I apply it on my project, it does not work, in fact I get the above error

Comment: Check if your tests are in the `test` folder

Comment: Yes it is in the right folder. I'm beginning to think that there are some conflicts in the dependency, although there are no errors reported (but only those relating to the absence of org.junit package) . I do not know what to think.

Comment: Doubt on the Test folder: In my project i've created folders src/test/java using  the "Project" perspective of the Project Pane. So when i switch to the "Android" perspective, the package "com.office. --"  it has not the gray written "(test)".   could this be the problem? perhaps the package and the test folder  should not be created in this way?

Comment: Your file should be in app/src/test/java. You don't need to extend `InstrumentationTestCase` if you will only work with jUnit.

Comment: Yes it's what I have done, I removed the extension. The test file is in app/src/test/java, in the same package of the corresponding class; but I still keep getting the "error: package org.junit does not exist".

Comment: Edit your post and add `build.gradle` file please

Comment: I added an answer, check if it works for you. I run that and it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add annotations (`@Before` and `@Test`) to your methods to be recognised as test methods.

You don't need to extend `InstrumentationTestCase` if you will run only jUnit tests.

I tested this class and I get a fail as it's expected:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class exampleTest {
    String ob1, ob2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ob1 = "hi";
        ob2 = "bye";
    }

    @Test
    public void  testEx()throws Exception{
        assertEquals("Error", ob1, ob2);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, in my project does not work. I always have "error: package org.junit does not exist".  Instead this works in simple project created ( Calculator )to make quick test

Comment: Do you need `sourceSets` and `testOptions` sections in your `build.gradle`? Try removing those

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help